# Use Object or proper data type

Tags: java, object

I am putting the data into the `HashMap` of type `<String, Object>`. I'm using object because I don't know what is coming from the backend. Now my question is, when I have to use that object, should I convert that to proper data type? Is there any issue if I use them as object.

Comment: How are you going to use it without casting it? Can you give us a little code?

Comment: I'm not doing any further calculations on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert them to proper data type to call your methods on them. use `instance Of` operator to check their types.

Answer (score 2):

At the time of accessing it you will have to convert it into proper datatype.

Answer (score 1):

well if you want to use any method which is only in your subclass and not in java.lang.Object you will have to "convert" (i.e. cast) it to the proper type

Answer (score 0):

You can use Object type as Value but you need to take care of convertion while doing retriving of that values.

Answer (score 0):

In `Java` you cannot call on an instance the methods that are not declared in the instance' type. If you want to use some methods from a specific type that is a subclass of `Object`, than yes, you need to make a cast.